# how to determine maxReceivedMessageSize for a list of up to 2000 items of a given class

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the following web method

```
public List<ExtractDistribution> GetExtractsRecipients(String settlementDate, bool automatic)
```

The **ExtractDistribution** class is defined like this

```
public class ExtractDistribution
    {
        public bool selected;
        public string account ;
        public string email ;
        public string PDFfileName ;
        public string PDFpassword ;
        public DateTime reportDate;
        public int sendStatus ;
        public string sendStatusDesc ;
        public DateTime sendStatusDate ;
        public string parameters ;
        public string extensions ;
}
```

To which value do I need to set the **maxReceivedMessageSize** in the binding, to allow up to 2000 items in the list of the web method **GetExtractsRecipients**

How is the calculation made ?

Comment: You'll need to know the maximum possible size of all those strings (in ExtractDistribution), otherwise the max size for 1 record (let alone 2000) is infinite.

Comment: @BlargleMonster ok...lets asume that each string is 100 characters long, how would you go about doing the calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rough estimate.  Assuming the strings are encoded with ASCII/UTF8:

```
bool selected - 1 byte
string account - 100 bytes
string email - 100 bytes
string PDFfileName - 100 bytes
string PDFpassword - 100 bytes
DateTime reportDate - 8 bytes
int sendStatus - 4 bytes
string sendStatusDesc - 100 bytes
DateTime sendStatusDate - 8 bytes
string parameters - 100 bytes
string extensions - 100 bytes
Total - 721 bytes
```

So you'll need 721 * 2000 or 1442000 bytes (~1442 kb) for that many objects.  However, this doesn't take into account the envelope for the message.  If you are using soap it will be distinctly larger than using a JSON envelope.

Given the range it might be safe to assume about 2 mb (2048 kb) for your 2000 records.

**EDIT:** My thinking was a little sloppy.  A SOAP envelope shouldn't be that much larger in this case than a JSON envelope.  However if you have to take into account non-english characters then the size of the strings can go up to 400 bytes each which would significantly increase your total message size.  Hopefully this answer explain the process for deciding what size to use though and you can take all the little details about your situation into account.

Answer (score 0):

Set maxReceivedMessageSize to the maximum! (long.Max)

Here's the secret: This doesn't really cost you anything. This setting comes to protect you from DOS attachs where someone will send a very large request and your service will start to choke. You have other ways around that like adding authentication. Anyway this setting is not useless, it does reduce some kind of risk (even in case of authentication), but depending on how your app is consumed and by who this may not be a relevant risk.